# How to save grayscale image with proper colormap using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I want to write/save this grayscale(2d) image with unique pixel values [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [image]

with opencv, but when I save it using this

```py
cv2.imwrite('test.jpg', image)
```

I see a dark image with very faint pixels for the above values

[image: cv image]

How can I save my image using opencv and still ensure proper colormap is followed? Is there a better library to save this kind of low pixel grayscale images?

Comment: The proper "colormap" is saved. The image is a grayscale image with intensity values very close to `0` (black), that's the image and that's what opencv saves. You might want to apply a colormap in opencv via the `applyColorMap` function. See: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html. Another option is to save the figure with `matplotlib` or normalize the image before saving it with opencv to better see the darker values.

Comment: Your first image was generated by something that assigns distinct colors to each value.  Your second one doesn't do any mapping at all, and the values are all too close together to see the difference.  You need to apply a mapping as suggested by @stateMachine.

Comment: Post your code!!!!

Comment: if you want to **look at** a pretty picture, apply a colormap. if you want **data**, do NOT do that. pretty pictures aren't data, they're visualizations *of* data

Comment: With `matplotlib` colormap is relative to the pixel values per image, and not consistent without color limit min-max values. I want to save images like the first one for better visualization

Answer (score 0):

You should not consider this image as grayscale (the values do not correspond to intensities) but as labelled (the values indicate different "objects" that have been segmented out and assigned a sequence number).

The image has been displayed with pseudocoloring, i.e. assigning distinct colors to the distinct integer values for legibility.

In the first place *do not save the image with lossy compression*, this will spoil the data by modifying the values, hence the labels. In particular, avoid JPEG ! Suitable formats are PNG and BMP.

You can choose a palettized format that is able to keep the pseudocoloring visible in the picture. If not possible, save as uncompressed grayscale, and apply a color palette when displaying. A grayscale palette is also possible if you increase the contrast (e.g. values 0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120).